# jquery returning array with tag context and length instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I worked with js in a pretty simple way.
I wish now to tend toward more of an object oriented approach and so I divided my script to different files. one for the main JS and one for each object.
But for some reason, when I use Jquery, it returns a weird output instead of what I'm used to.
How can I solve this?

```
//********************execution flow********************//
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('js/client_pages_OBJ.js', function () {createNavbar()});
})

function createNavbar(){
    $("#navigation").empty();
    client_pages_OBJ.importPages(client_pages_OBJ.createPagesList, $("#navigation"));
    console.log($("#navigation"));
    $("#navigation").find('>:first-child>:first-child').addClass('active')
}
```

received output:

```
[div#navigation, context: document, selector: "#navigation"]
```

Comment: Try to log only #navigation and see what's in there. If you use jQuery, it will enhance things. This is why some output can look strange. And in javascript each array is an object.

Comment: sorry, the output i copied is without .get(0).
with it, appears only the first member of the array and he is not a jquery object